# Overlapping rows in Twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have got a problem with rows which are overlapping in this following code:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top  ">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Buy Sell Rent Everyting">
                        Site.com
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">NL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">ENG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">SP</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><h1>This is my header</h1></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><img src="img/MyPicture.JPG" height="300"></div>
    </div>
```

In my browser the last rows lies over the navbar. Could it be that it has got something to do with the second row being outside the container? If so where should I  define the container.

Here is the jsfiddle text: http://jsfiddle.net/L9GJE/

Comment: Also... having [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) replicating this would be helpful :-)

Comment: jsfiddle does not have the bootstrap library. Tried before on Bootply but it doesn't work at the moment

Comment: Fake it by referencing it in the HTML portion via `<script>`

Comment: I added the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L9GJE/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap `<div class="row">` with a `<div class="container">`

e.g.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      ....
   </div>
</div>
```

So whenever you use the `navbar` you'll need to keep in mind that it is `fixed` and you will need to add `margin` or `padding` from the `top` so your rows won't overlap.

Comment: [Relevant Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro): "Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding."

Answer (score 1):

Your navbar is fixed, so, you need to add margin-top to second `row`.

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar was not made correctly, here is the correct usage of the [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) class:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>This is my header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but his navbar is fixed (I'm guessing he want that). Because of that, he need to add margin-top to first wrapper element after navbar. Fixed elements overlap other elements, so we need to add padding or margin to element with lower z-index.